# What is the connection between IDT and IRQ?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt

I want to intercept some interrupts in the kernel, and just wrap the original function with some of my code. Mainly for learning purpose.

I already know how to intercept page-faults, and double-faults, through the IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table), and it works just fine.

So now I want to intercept the RTC, which is at IRQ 8. I didn't find anything specific, but after reading some code I think that the IRQ is inside the IDT, and that it starts at the 32th entry (in code `IRQ = IDT+32;`). So I ran an example where I changed the 40th entry of the IDT, and nothing happened. (just in case, I ran it again while changing the 0x3a entry, even I'm pretty sure it's in decimal - nothing happened.)

So my questions:

- Am I right that IRQ = IDT+32? (If not, where is the table that dispatches IRQs?)
- Am I right expecting a kernel crash after intercepting the RTC? (I just redirect it to a function that just prints 'Hello, World!')

In case it matters, my test are run inside a VM. I run linux Mint on a 64 bit machine (gust & host). The host has Windows 7.

Comment: If you attempt to re-enter the kernel from interupt state, eg. to try an print something, (where would it print to?), I can't really see that going well at all:)

Comment: I want to print it to the kernel-ring-buffer with `printk`. After I let it work for sometime I look at the `dmesg` and see my setup prints, but no print from the function that is now in the IDT.